# Is there and adjunction between $Cat$ and $Fp$?

Tags: category-theory

By $Fp$ I mean the category of cartesian categories with cartesian functors (product preserving). The name comes from "finite product".

I can't seem to find information on this.

There's an adjunction between $MonCat$ and $Fp$, so finding an adjunction between $Cat$ and $MonCat$ would also help.

[I found this nlab entry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+cartesian+category) but the construction of a cartesian category out of a category doesn't even use its morphisms as far as I can see, so I'm confused about it.

Comment: It certainly does use its morphisms, see under "explicit construction." The article answers your question.

Comment: @KevinArlin I see it now, thanks.